# Odoo v10 HR payroll community version

Tags: odoo

Hello guys i am working on odooV10 community version. I have installed my own module for HR payroll and leave management with a DB consisting of records. My question is MY created module wants to install on another machine. How can i achieve that.??? is that database entries stored in the same module folder??? 
I hope someone can clear my doubt..
for more clarity:

- I will install payroll in my system
- edit all entries as i want
- copying this payroll module in another machine

  These are the steps that i planning to do.

Comment: what you can do is to export your current data into a CSV file, put that file into your module folder and point to it as a "data file" in __openerp__.py

Comment: can you recommend some tutorial or link for this... Im newbie in this odoo...@MICROCOM

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to have a set of default records that always install with your module?

If so, you want to load these into a `data` file that will make these a permanent part of your module.

You can [read about data files in the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/data.html) and/or review how Odoo does this in the core code.

If you're only needing to get the records into another database, you can Export from the first database and Import into the next.

Comment: yes @traviswi want to load these into a data file that will make these a permanent part of your module.  How to do DB migration in odoo10

Comment: @SanuKyadav Did you see the documentation about the data files? Odoo core has some examples, usually files ending in `_data.xml`. Database migration is an entirely different animal, typically only done by Odoo SA directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, you must choose the one that best fits your situation:

- If you want to pass information from one database to another you can use the export option of odoo:

1) Go to the tree view of the model you want to export and select the record (s).

2) Expand the More option and click on Export.

3) Select the fields you want to export and save the csv file that will be used to import.

To import: you must go to the tree view and select the Import button that should appear next to the Create option and follow the steps indicated.

- If you want to keep the data in your modules to be created every time you install you must create data.xml files
- You can export the database directly. You can visit this page to know the steps to do it from odoo
  [Create-backup](https://www.targetintegration.com/servers/how-to-create-backup-of-the-database-and-restore-the-database-in-openerpodoo)
  I hope I've helped